# Eigenvalues being roots of $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

> Let $V$ be $n$ dimensional vector space, with basis $v_1,\cdots,v_n$. Suppose $\mathscr{A}: V\to V$ is an invertible linear operator, such that $\mathscr{A}(v_i)\in \{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$, $i=1,\cdots,n$. Show that $\mathscr{A}$ is diagonal, and has roots of $1$ as eigenvalues.

My attempt: show that $v_1,\mathscr{A}v_1,\cdots,\mathscr{A}^{n-1}v_1$ are linearly independent, and then has eigenvalues: $n$ roots of $1$, so $\mathscr{A}$ can be diagonalisable. But how?

Comment: What you want to prove may be false. Take $\mathcal{A}$ that swaps $v_2$ and $v_3$, and sends all the other basis vectors to themselves. Your list would then just be the vector $v_1$ listed $n$ times.

Comment: A linear operator on a vector spaces cannot be diagonal, though it can be diagonalisable. Its matrix with respect to a specific basis can be diagonal. Here you are probably talking about its matrix with respect to the given basis it would be better to make that clear in the formulation.

Comment: Prove that $\mathcal{A}$ induces a permutation of the basis, and hence there is a $k$ such that $\mathcal{A}^k=I$.

Comment: The statement given does not specify the field the vector space is defined over. If that field does not contain sufficiently many roots of unity (for instance if it is $\Bbb R$) then $\mathscr A$ may fail to be diagonalisable, even though its matrix would be diagonalisable over$~\Bbb C$ if the original field is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. For fields of finite characteristic, the matrix might fail to be diagonalisable even over the algebraic closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof works on the assumption that your question was defined over $\mathbb{C}$. Because $\mathscr{A}$ is invertible, it must map bases to bases, and given the further restriction that $\mathscr{A} v_i=v_j$ for some $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, we can find a permutation $\pi$ such that $\mathscr{A} v_i=v_{\pi{(i)}}$. Then, in the basis $\{v_i, \ldots, v_n\}$, $\mathscr{A}$ can be represented as the permutation matrix:

$$P_{\pi}= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{e_{\pi{(1)}}}\\
\vdots\\
\mathbb{e_{\pi{(n)}}}\end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix has orthogonal columns, and thus acts as an isometry, i.e., $\|P_{\pi} x\|=\|x\|\ \ \forall \ x$. If $x$ were an eigenvector of $P_{\pi}$, we would have  $\|P_{\pi} x\|=\|\lambda x\| \implies |\lambda|=1$. Depending on the order $m$ of the permutation, your eigen values would be $e^{2 \pi i k/m}$.